# Run a R function with multiple parameters in parallel mode

Tags: r, performance, parameters, parallel-processing, dataframe

I have the function

```
function1 <- function(df1, df2, int1, int2, char1)
{
...
return(newDataFrame)
}
```

which has 5 inputs: the first 2 are data frames, then I have two integers and a string. 
The function returns a new data frame.

So far I am running this function 8 times sequentially:

```
newDataFrame1 <- function1(df1, df2, 1, 1, "someString")
newDataFrame2 <- function1(df1, df2, 2, 0, "someString")
newDataFrame3 <- function1(df1, df2, 3, 0, "someString")
newDataFrame4 <- function1(df1, df2, 4, 0, "someString")
newDataFrame5 <- function1(df1, df2, 5, 0, "someString")
newDataFrame6 <- function1(df1, df2, 6, 0, "someString")
newDataFrame7 <- function1(df1, df2, 7, 0, "someString")
newDataFrame8 <- function1(df1, df2, 8, 0, "someString")
```

and at the end I am combining results using rbind():

```
newDataFrameTot <-  rbind(newDataFrame1, newDataFrame2, newDataFrame3, newDataFrame4, newDataFrame5, newDataFrame6, newDataFrame7, newDataFrame8)
```

I wanted to run this in parallel using library(parallel) but I'm not able to figure out how to make this work. I am trying:

```
cluster <- makeCluster(detectCores())
result <- clusterApply(cluster,1:8,function1)
newDataFrameTot <- do.call(rbind,result)
```

but this don't work unless my function function1() has only one parameter that I loop from 1 to 8. But this is not my case since I need to pass 5 inputs. 
How can I make this work in parallel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To iterate over more than one variable, `clusterMap` is very useful. Since you're only iterating over `int1` and `int2`, you should use the "MoreArgs" option to specify the variables that you *aren't* iterating over:

```
cluster <- makeCluster(detectCores())
clusterEvalQ(cluster, library(xts))
result <- clusterMap(cluster, function1, int1=1:8, int2=c(1, rep(0, 7)),
                MoreArgs=list(df1=df1, df2=df2, char1="someString"))
df <- do.call('rbind', result)
```

In particular, if `df1` and `df2` are data frames and they are specified as iteration variables rather than using "MoreArgs", `clusterMap` will iterate over the columns of those data frames rather than passing the entire data frame to `function1`, which isn't what you want.

Note that it's important to use named arguments so that the arguments are passed correctly.

---

*A Note on Performance*

If either `df1` or `df2` is very large, you may get better performance by exporting them to the cluster workers. This avoids sending them in every task, but requires a wrapper function. It also means that you no longer need to use the "MoreArgs" option:

```
clusterExport(cluster, c('df1', 'df2', 'function1'))
wrapper <- function(int1, int2, char1) {
  function1(df1, df2, int1, int2, char1)
}
result <- clusterMap(cluster, wrapper, 1:8, c(1, rep(0, 7)), "someString")
```

This allows `df1` and `df2` to be reused if the workers perform multiple tasks, but is pointless if the number of tasks is equal to the number of workers.

Comment: Thanks, just trying this one. I get an error since it says that cannot find the "as.xts" function. But library(xts) is specified in the main function.

Comment: I have just added library(xts) inside the function that is being called in parallel. I get the results now! Thanks. Anyway, the data frames that are returned by each iteration are then concatenated horizontally while I would need these data frames to be combined by rows. So far I am using rbind of each single data frame that results after I call the function under each iteration. Is it possible to tell clusterMap to combine by row? Further, why I don't take the column names in the combined results? But thank you for your help.

Comment: clusterMap returns the results in a list by default, in the same way as clusterApply. You should be able to combine the results using `do.call('rbind', result)`.

Comment: Thank you now everything works. That was very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

To pass one variable you would have to use the parallel version of `lapply` or `sapply` like you tried. However, to pass many variables, you have to use the parallel version of `mapply` or `Map`. That would be `clusterMap`, so try

```
clusterMap(cluster, function1, df1, df2, 1:8, c(1, rep(0, 7)), "someString")
```

**Edit** As pointed out in the comments, this will throw an error. Normally, arguments of length 1 (such as `"someString"` in this example) should be recycled to the length of the other ones (e.g. `1:8` in this example). The error thrown is due to the fact that the data frames are not recycled in the same manner, but are treated as lists instead, so their columns are repeated rather than the whole data frame. This is why you got the error `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` because inside `function1`, it attempted to use `$` on the *extracted column* of a data frame, which was a vector, rather than the data frame itself. There are two remedies to this. The first is to pass additional arguments inside `MoreArgs`, as mentioned in the other answer. This requires your arguments to be named (which is good practice anyway). The second way to fix it, is to wrap each data frame in a list:

```
clusterMap(cluster, function1, list(df1), list(df2), 1:8, c(1, rep(0, 7)), "someString")
```

This will work, because now the whole data frames `df1` and `df2` will be recycled. The difference can be seen e.g. by looking at the output of `rep(df1, 2)` vs `rep(list(df1), 2)`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I'm getting the error: "Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 8 nodes produced errors; first error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" what is the problem here?

Comment: This message is due to an error that occurs inside `function1`, so without knowing what it looks like it's hard to tell. Could you update your post with full details of the function as well as the arguments you are passing to it?

Comment: I am trying to update with a working example. But how can I identify at what stage the error is thrown in my function1()?

Comment: If you try running it for one set of parameters it may produce a more helpful error message, or you can always go through the body of the function line by line and see where the error occurs. `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` means that you are using `$` to access the elements of a vector, when you should be using it on a data frame or list. So check for example the lines where you have something like `object$variable` and make sure that "object" is a data frame or list?

Comment: Hi konvas, I don't see any problem in function1 and, in fact, it all works fine when I run sequentially, as showed in the post. I get this problem when I try using the line that you kindly suggested. Is it possible that I have to specify that df1 and df2 are data frames when I use thse as input in clusterMap()?

Comment: Well I am unable to run the line I suggested on your actual example because I cannot reproduce it but as far as I can tell it doesn't contain any errors. If you provide some data to reproduce the problem, I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried to use this line without success, but I was able to run the line after adding the list of "MoreArgs" as suggested below by Steve Weston. Now I just need to combine results vertically and not horizontally how it seems to be done by clusterMap. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

As I had the same problem recently in R, I am attaching a link to a very useful website. This is a new multidplyr package, which enables parallel processing in R. It definitely works in Windows 10. :)

http://www.business-science.io/code-tools/2016/12/18/multidplyr.html

To help you with your code this would be the solution I would propose (did not test, but should work as I used it on another example)

```
#Install the packages
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/multidplyr")
require(multidplyr)
library(parallel)
cl <- detectCores()
cluster <- create_cluster(cores = cl)
cluster %>%
    # Assign libraries
    cluster_library("igraph") %>%
    cluster_library("tidyverse") %>%
    cluster_library("magrittr") %>%
    cluster_library("dplyr") %>%
    cluster_library("RColorBrewer") %>%
    # Assign values (use this to load functions or data to each core)
    cluster_assign_value("anyfunction", anyfunction)

result <- clusterMap(cluster, function1, int1=1:8, int2=c(1, rep(0, 7)),
            MoreArgs=list(df1=df1, df2=df2, char1="someString"))
```